# Support of Oracle streams in 12c

Tags: oracle, stream, database-replication

I read that Stream are not going to be supported in 12c and any further versions. Is that true?

We have two databases source and destination. We were using STREAMS propagation between them but recently we replaced this with Advance queue propagation. As part of that we have changed our source queues (now created using DBMS_AQADM package instead of DBMS_STREAMS_ADM), using schedules , subscribers e.t.c. but at destination DB we did not change anything. Still queues on the destination DB's are created using DBMS_STREAMS_ADM. Also we use Custom apply handlers at destination db.

Now considering the point that STREAMS will not be supported after 12c.1, we are planning to use DBMS_AQADM package to create destination queues as well. but my question is will apply handler, and apply processes which are created by using DBMS_APPLY_ADM package will be supported if there wont be nay STREAMS in the future?

Thanks
Peeush

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is replacing Stream with Golden Gate, a full data integration software package.  There should be documentation on their website somewhere.